# Youtube-DL: Date Modified

Tags: powershell, youtube-dl

Using PowerShell on Windows I'm downloading a channel similar to this:

```
youtube-dl.exe `
    --format 18 `
    --continue `
    --ignore-errors `
    --no-overwrites `
    --add-metadata `
    --xattrs `
    -o "\\srvds\Media\Youtube\Channel\%(upload_date)s.%(title)s.%(ext)s"  `
    https://www.youtube.com/user/Channel
```

Is there a way to change the file-modified date to match the date of the file upload date/time inside Youtube-DL?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean using that tool, I have no idea. Yet, easily done using PowerShell, and there are examples of messing with times stamps all over the web.

For Example, a simple search using...

> powershell change file modified date

… yields …

> Use PowerShell to Modify File Access Time Stamps
>   https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/06/01/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps

```
Set-FileTimeStamps function

Function Set-FileTimeStamps

{

 Param 
(
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$path,
    [datetime]$date = (Get-Date)
)

Get-ChildItem -Path $path |

ForEach-Object 
{
     $_.CreationTime = $date
     $_.LastAccessTime = $date
     $_.LastWriteTime = $date }
} 



#42 : How to change modified date of file using Powershell? 
http://powershell-tips.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-change-modified-date-of-file.html

ls | where { $_.Name -eq "webcam-toy-photo2.jpg" } | foreach { $_.LastWriteTime="9/23/1942 10:10 PM" }
```

Comment: Yeah, the goal was to do it in one pass with youtube-dl - pull file and use the "posted datetime" as the modified date. There are some hidden magics in console apps like it and figured I'd ask before I delved into PowerShell'y ways of doing it. I guess the question and tag does need a bit more clarification.